# T-SQL Query, joining two tables but only returning data from table 1 for 1 row in second table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

OK, it's kind of hard to describe what I need to get out of SQL in a single subject row. I hope the subject does not turn away too many folks...

I have two tables, one that has a Ship ID, tracking number and the shipping cost.

```
Declare @ship as table
(
    shipID varChar(25),
    TrkID VarChar(50),
    shp_Cost money
)

Insert into @ship Values('1000000058','075637240645964',13.1900)
Insert into @ship Values('1000000077','075637240646671',10.3300)
Insert into @ship Values('1000000078','075637240646695',12.8300)
Insert into @ship Values('1000000079','075637240646725',11.2100)
```

This has a 1:Many relationship where this is a single shipment but it may have many line items in it.  The second table has the line items and for demo reasons it looks like this...

```
Declare @ship_2 as table
(
    shipID VarChar(25),
    trkID VarChar(50),
    Item_SKU VarChar(50),
    Ship_Quantity int
)

Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000058','075637240645964','P025.3',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000058','075637240645964','P100.1',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000058','075637240645964','P21.1',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000058','075637240645964','P024',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000058','075637240645964','A-P927',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000058','075637240645964','PBC',500)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000077','075637240646671','P213.99',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000077','075637240646671','P029',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000077','075637240646671','P-05.3',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000078','075637240646695','P0006.1',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000078','075637240646695','P01.67-US',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000078','075637240646695','P09.1',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000078','075637240646695','P022.1',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000078','075637240646695','P08.3',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000079','075637240646725','P02',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000079','075637240646725','P0006.1',25)
Insert into @ship_2 Values('1000000079','075637240646725','P1.4',25)
```

So what I need is a way to join the two tables and provide the shipping details to include the cost of the shipping in one result set. Not really a problem until you consider that only one of the line items should carry the cost of the shipping.   If there are 6 line items I only need to return the shipping cost on the first line item and 0 on the remaining 5 rows.

I am currently at a complete loss of how I can accomplish this at the moment.  It will all be in a stored proc and I can create temp tables or declare tables as needed.

Any one have a suggestion on what I need to look for.

Thanks for any help our guidance you can provide.

Tim

Comment: Whoopss...   SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use CTE for this:

```
;with cte as
(
    select s.shipID, 
        s.TrkID, 
        s.shp_Cost, 
        s2.Item_SKU, 
        s2.Ship_Quantity, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by s.shipid order by s.shipid) rn
    from @ship s
    inner join @ship_2 s2
        on s.shipID = s2.shipID
)
select shipID, 
    TrkID, 
    case when rn = 1 then shp_Cost else 0 end shp_cost,
    Item_SKU,
    Ship_Quantity
from cte
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8296/1)

Comment: This worked great!  Thanks!  Now I am heading off to learn more about CTE and where else I can use it.